# Error in R: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, datetime, plyr, posixct, as.date

I would like some help with understanding and fixing an error message that I encountered when I executed the command `View(combined_data)`. The error message that appeared was:

> r error 4 (Error in vec_data(x) * TICS_PER_SECOND : non-numeric argument to binary operator )

Prior to encountering this error message, I executed the following code to combine CSV files into a single dataframe using `ldply`.

```
library(plyr) # for the ldply function
library(here) # for the here function
library(readr) # for the read_csv function
mydir = here("folder", "subfolder")
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
combined_data = ldply(myfiles, read_csv, skip=5) # skipping 5 rows in each file
```

As far as I could tell, this code worked correctly (the combined_data had correct number of rows and columns). When I ran the the command `str(combined_data)`, R reported that the error was caused by the column ***$ In Bed Time*** (class "hms" "difftime").

My vain attempt to correct this was to convert some of the variables (numeric was imported as character, dates were imported as character) to their correct classes (converting character back to numeric and dates respectively). This did not have the desired effect and resulted in further issues.

```
combined_data[8:18] <- as.numeric(unlist(combined_data[8:18]))
combined_data[c(2,4,6)] <- format(as.Date(unlist(combined_data[c(2,4,6)]), format="%m/%d/%Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
combined_data[c(3,5,7)] <- format(as.POSIXct(unlist(combined_data[c(3,5,7)]), format="%I:%M:%S %p"), "%I:%M:%S %p")
```

Variables 2,4,6 are dates and formatted as 8/20/2020
Variables 3,5,7 are times and formatted as 12:35:00 AM.
After this, I could execute the command `View(combined_data)` but all my time variables (originally class "hms" "difftime") were changed to NA's. Also, while my dates displayed correctly, their class did not change to Date.

Comment: The first thing you need to learn is to NOT apply destructive assignments to your data. I also think there's some missing code. It's hard to imagine why an "hms" or "difftime" object could be the result of read_csv. And **as always** please provide data. See [MCVE]

Comment: Hello, @IRTFM! Thank you for your feedback. I figured out a workaround. I did not realize initially but some of the files that I was importing had 0 rows (after the header row). I just removed those files from the list "myfiles" before running the ldply() function and it fixed the error I got from executing View() command. And thank you for the link to minimal reproducible example article. I will make sure that my future posts meet those guidelines.